# How can I reduce an array of objects depending by an id

Tags: javascript

expected output:

```
[{id: 1, atributo: {id: 20}, valor: 1753,96},
{id: 2, atributo: {id:21}, valor: 1520}]
```

I have this array of objects:

```
myArr = [{id: 21852, atributo: {id: 20}, valor: "876.98"},
{id: 21853, atributo: {id:21}, valor: "760"},
{id: 21858, atributo: {id:20}, valor: "876.98"},
{id: 21859, atributo: {id:21}, valor: "760"}]
```

I want to agroup the arrays with same id inside "atributo" and sum the values of "valor".

I tryed something like this:

```
  const agroup = myArr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    if (a && a.atributo.id === b.atributo.id) {
      return a + Number(b.valor);
    } else {
      return { ...a };
    }
  });
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use something else than just `reduce`. `Array.reduce` will return only 1 value. You are looking for [Group By](https://gomakethings.com/a-vanilla-js-equivalent-of-lodashs-groupby-method/)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try use Group By.

Comment: @JonathanLarouche note that 1 value could be a new array. The link you provide even uses `reduce`

Comment: @PatrickEvans, you are right, I might have written this badly, I wanted to point out that simply using .reduce returning an single object or value wont do the job. Need further logic inside the reducer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this one. You seek for an existing entry and if found you sum up the `valor` property value:

```js
const myArr = [{id: 21852, atributo: {id: 20}, valor: "876.98"},
{id: 21853, atributo: {id:21}, valor: "760"},
{id: 21858, atributo: {id:20}, valor: "876.98"},
{id: 21859, atributo: {id:21}, valor: "760"}];


const res = myArr.reduce((res, curr) => {

  const existing = res.find((e) => e.atributo.id === curr.atributo.id);
  if (existing) {
    existing.valor = +existing.valor + +curr.valor;
  } else {
    res.push(curr);
  }
  
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: If you found it useful, consider marking this as an answer or leaving an upvote so the future readers could benefit from it. That's how SO works ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array and add a new id property.

```js
var data = [{ id: 21852, atributo: { id: 20 }, valor: "876.98" }, { id: 21853, atributo: { id: 21 }, valor: "760" }, { id: 21858, atributo: { id: 20 }, valor: "876.98" }, { id: 21859, atributo: { id: 21 }, valor: "760" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { valor, atributo }) => {
        var temp = r.find(q => q.atributo.id === atributo.id);
        if (temp) {
            temp.valor += +valor;
        } else {
            r.push({ id: r.length + 1, atributo, valor: +valor });
        }        
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a vanilla version of group by - Something like the one below :

```
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Object.values(   // Convert Map to Array
    arr.reduce(
        function(a,i)
        { 
            i.valor = parseFloat(i.valor);  // converting current valor to float
            i.id = a.lenght+1;              // updating the id
            if (a[i.atributo.id]!== undefined)  // if such atributo already exists..
            {
                a[i.atributo.id].valor += i.valor;  // sum it with current valor
            }
            else
            {
                a[i.atributo.id]=i;  // append new element to valor. // I use Map to have an easier lookup for elements in the accumulator
            } 
            return a;
        },
        {}
     )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce and find the if the object with this id is already created on each iteration

```js
const myArr = [{
    id: 21852,
    atributo: {
      id: 20
    },
    valor: "876.98"
  },
  {
    id: 21853,
    atributo: {
      id: 21
    },
    valor: "760"
  },
  {
    id: 21858,
    atributo: {
      id: 20
    },
    valor: "876.98"
  },
  {
    id: 21859,
    atributo: {
      id: 21
    },
    valor: "760"
  }
];

let index = 1;
const finalArr = myArr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const existingObjectIndex = acc.findIndex(i => i.atributo.id === item.atributo.id);
  if (existingObjectIndex < 0) {
    acc.push({
      id: acc.length + 1,
      atributo: {
        id: item.atributo.id
      },
      valor: Number(item.valor)
    });
  } else {
    acc[existingObjectIndex].valor += Number(item.valor);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(finalArr);
```